# A word/expression: more "valuable" than "valuable"?

Tags: word-usage

I would like to say that something is "very valuable".
Do we have better word/expression that can do the job?
The suggestions in the other thread sound extravagant compared to what I would like to express.

Comment: I saw that thread but I still expect more discussions and more "valuable" suggestions indeed.

Comment: @user76911 do you mean valuable in monetary terms or sentimental terms?

Comment: @aaa90210: in general actually. Thanks for your clarifying question.

Comment: It's funny that three people marked down my question. I hope everyone will be more careful taking the same action in the future. In my case, I did not have that much time to post a question that I thought did not make sense and for that I did not really need an answer. 

In particular for this question, I made it clear above that I saw the other thread, but I did not find what I need from the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Valuable' is a term that limits something to mere value. It's quite definitive. If you want to describe something in a way that takes it to a whole new level, you could use 'invaluable' or 'priceless'. These words suggest that it's hard to put a value on the thing being described because it's too good or too useful.
When you say that a thing is valuable to you, you add a sense of possession to it. That sense is slightly lost when you use 'invaluable'- it means that the thing is  too valuable to be described in terms of value.
'Invaluable' suggests importance too; importance that comes along with worth and possession. 
If you still find it necessary to retain 'valuable', you could add an adverb like 'immensely' or 'extremely' before 'valuable'.
Hope that makes sense.